# Infinitely presented group where every finite sub-presentation is virtually free

Tags: gr.group-theory

Does there exist a finitely generated non-finitely presentable group
$$
 G=\langle S \mid R\rangle
$$
with $S$ finite, where we can enumerate $R=\{r_1,r_2,\ldots\}$ such that for every finite subset $I\subset \mathbb{N}$, the group
$$
 G_I=\langle S \mid \{r_i\mid i\in I\}\rangle
$$
is virtually free?

One potential candidate is the lamplighter $\mathbb{Z}_2\wr\mathbb{Z}$ with the presentation
$$
 \langle a,t \mid a^2, [a,t^kat^{-k}] \textrm{ for all } k\in\mathbb{Z}\rangle.
$$

(edit) Let me ask a more specific question related to lamplighters. Is it true that if
$$
 G_I=\langle a,t \mid a^2, [a,t^kat^{-k}] \textrm{ for all } k\in I\rangle
$$
is virtually free for some finite set $I\subset\mathbb N$, then for every large enough $k$, $G_{I\cup\{k\}}$ is also virtually free?

Comment: If you assume $S$ to be finite, you should say it.

Comment: @YCor I have to confess that I have been guilty of writing "Let $G = \langle X \rangle$ be a finitely generated group'' without explicitly saying that $X$ is assumed to be finite.

Comment: The truncated presentations $\Gamma_J=\langle a,t\mid a^2,[a,t^kat^{-k}]:k\in J\rangle$ are HNN extensions of finite groups, hence virtually free, when $J$ is a segment (i.e. equal to $\{1,\dots,n\}$ -- we can ignore those relators for $k\le 0$ since they are redundant).

Comment: @DerekHolt I have to confess that I already had to consider infinite generating subsets of finitely generated groups (including for which the diameter of the group remains infinite)

Comment: At this moment I'm unable to determine whether $\Gamma_{\{2,3\}}$ is virtually free.  [[In my previous comment, ignore "is a segment": I mean that $\Gamma_{\{1,\dots,n\}}$ is virtually free for every $n$, as a HNN-extension of a finite group, namely of $C_2^{n+1}$ over the isomorphism $C_2^n\times\{0\}\to \{0\}\times C_2^n$ given by $(x_1,\dots,x_n,0)\mapsto (0,x_1,\dots,x_n)$.]]

Comment: @YCor: I think the group $G_{\{1,3\}}$ is not virtually free. The kernel of the map to $\mathbb{Z}$ given by $a\mapsto 0, t\mapsto 1$ is a right-angled Coxeter group with vertices labelled by $a_k, k\in\mathbb{Z}$ ($a_k=t^kat^{-k}$ in $G_I$). Then I think $\langle a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3\rangle \cong (\mathbb{Z}_2 \ast \mathbb{Z}_2) \times (\mathbb{Z}_2\ast \mathbb{Z}_2)$, so is not virtually free.

Comment: @IanAgol yes the isomorphism with the RA Coxeter is true (I checked it in a 2006 Geom. Dedicata paper). So you're right, $\Gamma_{\{1,3\}}$ is not virtually free. Actually, a similar argument implies that $\Gamma_{\{2,3\}}$ is not virtually free, namely considering the subgroup generated by $\{a_0,a_2,a_3,a_5\}$.

Comment: @YCor: I suppose even more easily, when $a^2$ is not a relator, then the kernel of the map to $\mathbb{Z}$ will be a right-angled Artin group, hence not free when any other relator is present.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Can the statement about $G_{1,3}$ not being virtually free be extended to show that $G_{\{1,k\}}$ is virtually free only if $k=1,2$? Or more generally that the only free finite sub-presentations are the ones coming from segments?

Comment: @IanAgol sure, but this (removing $a^2$) is too obvious. Actually I think that the question should be amended by restricting $I$ to range over all finite subsets containing some given finite subset $I_0$ of the set of relators.

Comment: @DavidHume I think if you keep the relators $R_i$ and $R_j$, but not $R_{i+j}$ and $R_{i-j}$ (where $R_k = [a,t^kat^{-k}]$), then the subgroup generated by $\{a_0,a_i,a_j,a_{i+j}\}$ is $(\mathbb Z_2*\mathbb Z_2) \times(\mathbb Z_2*\mathbb Z_2)$. This in particular includes $G_{\{1,k\}}$ when $k \neq 2$.

Comment: About your last additional question: it might be that $G_{\{1,k\}}$ is not virtually free for any $k\ge 3$. This would be so if it's known that the RA Coxeter group whose commuting graph on generators is a $(k+1)$-gon is not virtually free, and I tend to believe that it's not. But I don't know enough about RA Coxeter groups to answer this right away.

Comment: @YCor, A RA Coxeter group is virtually free iff the graph is chordal.  This is not the case for a 4-gon or higher.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thanks. This shows that for every nonempty finite subset $I\subset\mathbf{N}_{>0}$ there exists $k\notin I$ such that $G_{I\cup\{k\}}$ is not virtually free (and even that for each such $I$ and every $k_0$, there exists $k\ge k_0$ such that $G_{I\cup\{k\}}$ is not virtually free).

Comment: @YCor: when talking about presentations, we sometimes distinguish between "finitely presented" and "finitely presentable": a group is finitely presentable if it has a finite presentation, while it is finitely presented if the presentation we are given is finite. Unfortunately, we don't distinguish between "finitely generated" and "finitely generable"!

Comment: @HJRW Indeed most existing uses of "finitely presented" are meant to be "finitely presentable".

Answer (score 3):

Here are some observations on your question. Firstly, consider the case that we take the presentation $\langle S | r_i\rangle$ for some $i$. This is a 1-relator group, and it will be virtually free iff $r_i$ is a power of a primitive element of $S$ (see [Theorem 3 of this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2038048?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) in the torsion case; and otherwise [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/26767/1345) and induction in the torsion-free case).

As a special case, suppose there is a relator $r_i$ which is not a proper power. Then it must be a primitive element in $S$, so $\langle S | r_i\rangle$ must be a free group on 1 fewer generator. Thus by induction on the rank, we may assume that all of the $r_i$ are proper powers of primitive elements.

Maybe there is a generalization of the theory of 1-relator groups (Freiheitzatz and Magnus-Moldovanskii hierarchy) to 1-relator quotients of virtually free groups? If so, the above arguments might carry over to this context. See [results of Howie](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms/s3-59.3.507) for some progress on this.

Comment: But the easiest argument is that $\langle a,t \mid [a,a^t] \rangle \cong \langle a,b,t \mid [a,b] = 1, b = a^t \rangle$ is an HNN extension of ${\mathbb Z}^2$ and hence has ${\mathbb Z^2}$ as a subgroup and cannot be virtually free. Of course that still requires the theory of HNN extensions.

Comment: @IanAgol Thanks, this seems like a very interesting approach in general, I just wondered if the community knew of an example before diving into this.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth pointing out that it's not terribly difficult to ensure that all the one-relator subpresentations are free. Just add an extra generator $t$ to $S$, add the relation $t$, and change every $r_i$ to $r_it$.  Of course, it's much harder to do something similar for larger subsets of relators, but then one gets out of the theory of one-relator groups.

Comment: @DerekHolt no need of HNN theory to see that it contains $\mathbf{Z}^2$ (generated by $\{a,a^t\}$): instead just map onto $\mathbf{Z}\wr\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: I suspect now that such presentations cannot exist. I think at least one should be able to use small cancellation theory to rule out presentations where the power is high, maybe at least 6.